# Multiple cameras with Raspberry Pi

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, beagleboard, pandaboard

I am working on a project that would require using at least 3 cameras to take a picture of the same object at different angles. I was thinking about using the raspberry pi to attach the 3 cameras to it but due to lack of CSI ports in it I can only use one. Is there a way to make this work?

The cameras can take pictures at different time intervals they don't have to work at the same time but witout much of a delay. I started looking into other board such as  BeagleBone or  PandaBoard ES but couldn't find much information about how many cameras I can use with these boards or how many CSI ports they have. It is also very important for my project that the board is android compatible as the software that I use to analyze the pictures runs on android.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are correct that you can only use one CSI camera module per Rasberry Pi.

Your best option here may be to use multiple USB cameras (if the image quality would be good enough), connected to the PI through a powered USB hub.

Do keep in mind that USB cameras can take a lot of processing power, so you may have problems if the time interval between each camera taking a picture needs to be very small?

Answer (score 0):

You can use IVPort, multiple Camera integration board. It allows you to connect up to 4 cameras per board. By using 4 boards,you will be able to connect maximum 16 cameras.